# State machine site level workflow activated but not showing in the workflow list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I developed my state machine workflow using Visual Studio 2010. It's successfully deployed; I can see the feature is activated on site collection level, but it's not showing up in the `List Settings --> Workflow Settings --> Add workflow`

Any Reason?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, actually I didn't experience it before with site workflows.

It shows where we create a list, just beside you can find site workflows. After successfully deployment and feature activation on site collection level you can start your workflow.

Below is the image of site workflows activation:

[image]

[This is also a helpful article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/416393/Create-a-Workflow-using-Visual-Studio).

Comment: Thanks Robert, I will try my best to improve these typo!!